# Wants to save(set) state in array of objects

Tags: reactjs, react-state

i have following fields on form.
**multiple devices on the form and on each devices there are nested fields .**
    -

- manufacture_date
- is_exportad
- name
- sign

When i submit the form i want to maintain all values in local state

like i.e devices{id1=>{name: "abc",sign: "xxx", is_exportad: true, manufacture_date: "12/10/2010" },id2=>{name: "hhh",sign: "xxfr", is_exportad: false, manufacture_date: "12/10/2011"}

so i can access values by doing similar to

> this.state.device[id1].name

when i need it later , i have tried like

```
 let model = id
        this.setState(prevState => {
            return {
                [model]: {
                    ...prevState[model],
                    [name]: url
                }
            };
        });
```

but this produce only {id1=>{name: "v", sign: "val" }, id2 => {name: "v", sign: "val" }}

Comment: how is the state object object defined?

Comment: this.state = {   devices:{}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to spread the existing values in `prevState` too.

```
let model = id
this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
        ...prevState,
        devices: {
            ...prevState.devices,
            [model]: {
                ...prevState.devices[model],
                [name]: url
            }
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: let me try this

Comment: @Anish I have editted to match the way you initialized your state